# FLASK, Heroku, React CORS issue

Tags: python, react-native, flask, heroku, cors

I have tried every solution available on the internet but failed. I have a Flask backend app and react native frontend app.Flask app is deployed on Heroku and React Native is running on localhost.

POST request from react native app to flask app which is on heroku failed. This error occurs 
**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://authentication-heroku.herokuapp.com/login' from origin 'https://localhost:19006' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.**

Its working fine when both apps are on localhost. But when flask is on heroku this error occurs. Below is my code.

#### React Code

```
let headers = {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        }

    let login_form = {
        email: email,
        password: password
    }
    axios.post('https://authentication-heroku.herokuapp.com/login', login_form, {headers: headers})
        .then(response => {
            console.log("response", response);
            if (response.statusText == "OK") {
                console.log("Ok");
                this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this);
                this.setState({ email: '',
                    password: '',
                    loading: false,
                    error: '',
                    loggedIn: true });
            } else {
                console.log("Not Ok");
                this.onLoginFail.bind(this);
                this.setState({ loggedIn: false,  error: 'Authentication Failed', password: '', email: '', loading: false });
            }
        })
        .catch(() => {
            this.onLoginFail.bind(this);
            this.setState({ loggedIn: false,  error: 'Authentication Failed', password: '', email: '', loading: false });
        });
```

#### Flask Code

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from flask_api import status
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'testdb'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb+srv://username@development-xec6b.gcp.mongodb.net/testdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
mongo = PyMongo(app, resources={r"/login": {"origins": "https://localhost:19006"}})

@app.route('/login',methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(origin='localhost',headers=['Content- Type','Authorization'])
def login():
    user = mongo.db.users
    email = request.json['email']
    password = request.json['password']
    email_exists = bool(user.find_one({'email': email}))
    pw_exists = bool(user.find_one({'password':password}))
    response = user.find_one({'email': email}).to_jon();
    response.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    response.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST')
    response.headers.set()
    if email_exists & pw_exists:
        return "Authenticated", status.HTTP_200_OK
    else:
        return "Record not found", status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: "I have tried every solution available on the internet but failed"—this is clearly false. Hyperbole doesn't help. Please try to be _accurate_ when asking questions here. See [ask].

Comment: Try https://httptoolkit.tech/will-it-cors/ and see what it says

Answer (score 0):

seems like a security issue since the two applications are not using the same protocol (HTTPS), it makes sense that they worked fine on localhost since they are not protocol bound, but now the flask rest api is on an https connection, i suggest you turn on cors policy `pip install -U flask-cors` and calling the middleware inside your app

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```

then try deploying your front end app to something very simple like serving it with an nginx proxy or an express rest api to see if the issue is anything other than these two possibilities, enjoy!